# Why sToString Show Null Value

Tags: c#

Here in this example I have initialized a variable integer and passed integer value to parametrized constructor then later I declare a instance method where I want to print the string vale then finally I call that method in the main program. bur when I print the value it show me NULL value, Why?

```
class CPrint
{
    int i = 100;
    string sToPrint;

    // here Initialize a default Constructor.
    public CPrint() { }
    //public CPrinter() : this("Default Constructor Value") {}

    // here defining a custom constructor which take one parameter of string value
    public CPrint(string s)
    {
        sToPrint = s;
    }

    // here defining a custom constructor which take one parameter of integer value

    public CPrint(int i)
    {
        sToPrint = Convert.ToString(i);
    }

    // instance method
    public void PrintString()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I have just printed ...{0}", sToPrint);

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CPrint p = new CPrint();
        p.PrintString(); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will print "Hello". It is correct. Are you showing us the right code?

Comment: @usr, the code was edited by another user, I have reverted it

Comment: That was one misleading edit!

Comment: @Wimmel Thanks for the edit back. I just meant to fix the formatting but added the code from my answer by mistake in the process.

Answer (score 2):

You used the `CPrint()` constructor in your Main method, which does nothing. So, `sToPrint` has not been initialized and hence it is `null`. If you want some non-null value, you will need to call the `CPrint(String)` or `CPrint(int)` constructor.

e.g,

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        CPrint p = new CPrint("Hello"); 
        p.PrintString(); Console.ReadLine(); 
    } 
}
```

It will print "Hello"

Comment: @Javaid malik I post your comment below, please do not edit the answer to comment. quote: Here I am not calling the null constructor, I am calling the paramaterized constructor which take the integer value then I convert integer to string value which should be 100 not null ?

Answer (score 2):

according to your code you will only get null value when you call default constructor. you can do as below.

```
public CPrint() {
        sToPrint = Convert.ToString(i);
}
```

in default constructor you don't assign value to `sToPrint` variable. that's why you get null value even though you set value to `i`

if you calling `CPrint(intvalue)`  then you should get output as bellow. it can't be null  because you set it as `sToPrint`

> I have just printed ...*intvalue*

if you want to get value of global variable inside your method with same name, you can use `this` keyword.

```
 public CPrint(int i)
    {
        sToPrint = Convert.ToString(this.i); // will print 100 
    } // put break point here and check sToPrint value
```

Comment: here in your comment you tell me that I am calling the default constructor no not at all. I am calling the parametrized constructor which take one argument then why it show a null value

Comment: you are calling `CPrint()`? isn't it?

Comment: public CPrint(int i)
    {
        sToPrint = Convert.ToString(this.i); // will print 100 
    }  when I debug this code the SToPrint value ==null Why?

Comment: you need to call `CPrint` with int parameter and then this constructor will call. put break point after assignment and check the value. you will get 100.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `int i = 100;` in the top of the class does not call the constructor. In fact, i is not used anywhere, so you should remove that line.

```
class CPrint
{
    //int i = 100;     // i is not used anywhere
    string sToPrint;
```

A way to solve this is using [constructor chaining](http://www.manjuke.com/2010/12/constructor-chaining-in-c.html); in the default constructor you can call another constructor when you supply a proper parameter:

```
public CPrint() : this(100) 
{ 
}

public CPrint(int i) : this (Convert.ToString(i))
{
}

public CPrint(string s)
{
    sToPrint = s;
}
```